# locking app into one orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

For a couple of different reasons, I'd like to ensure that my app only runs in landscape left orientation. I've unselected all of the other orientations under "Supported Device Orientations" in the target summary, set all of my storyboards to landscape, and added this to all of my classes:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

but I'm still having some problems. It launches into landscape left and that view remains in landscape left no matter what, but when I press a button that pushes a new view, it pushes the view but that one rotates if the device is turned. It also defaults back into portrait if I push another view and then press back in the navigation controller bar. Is there something more aggressive I need to do to ensure that all view controllers remain in landscape left at all times?

Comment: Have you implemented `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in the view controllers you are pushing?

Comment: yeah. I have it to go to LandscapeLeft.

Comment: is you xib in IB set to orientation landscape?  Running this in viewDidLoad will ensure it, but shouldn't be needed if you set supported device orientations already.  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];

Comment: I'm not using xibs, I'm using storyboard, but all of the view controllers are set to be in landscape.

Comment: There is some kind of Tech Note or something from Apple on how to support Landscape only, and I'm sure there are many threads on this here. Did you google iOS 'landscape only' etc?

Comment: Yeah, I did, didn't see much information that I haven't already done.